# How to compare results from Invoke-Sqlcmd?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

The goal is to compare database query results. However, using `Compare-Object` on the result of `Invoke-Sqlcmd` does not indicate the level of granularity of things that are different. How can I get that? Must I manually, field by field, do the comparison?

```
InputObject         SideIndicator
-----------         -------------
System.Data.DataRow <=
System.Data.DataRow <=
System.Data.DataRow <=
...
```

The results were generated by the following code.

```
$query = @"
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$TableName'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '$Schema'
"@
$t1 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SqlInstance -Database $Database -Query $query

$query2 = @"
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$TableName2'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '$Schema2'
"@
$t2 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SqlInstance2 -Database $Database2 -Query $query2

$t1.GetType()
$t1[0].GetType()
$t1[0] | fl * -Force
$t2[0] | fl * -Force
Write-Information -MessageData "comparing both query results"
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $t1 -DifferenceObject $t2

Write-Information -MessageData "comparing first elements of the array"
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $t1[0] -DifferenceObject $t2[0]

Write-Information -MessageData "comparing first element members"
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($t1[0]).COLUMN_NAME -DifferenceObject ($t2[0]).COLUMN_NAME
$query = @"
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$TableName'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '$Schema'
"@
$t1 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SqlInstance -Database $Database -Query $query

$query2 = @"
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$TableName2'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '$Schema2'
"@
$t2 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SqlInstance2 -Database $Database2 -Query $query2

$t1.GetType()
$t1[0].GetType()
$t1[0] | fl * -Force
$t2[0] | fl * -Force
Write-Information -MessageData "comparing both query results"
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $t1 -DifferenceObject $t2

Write-Information -MessageData "comparing first elements of the array"
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $t1[0] -DifferenceObject $t2[0]

Write-Information -MessageData "comparing first element members"
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($t1[0]).COLUMN_NAME -DifferenceObject ($t2[0]).COLUMN_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Compare-Object ($t1 | ConvertTo-CSV) ($t2 | ConvertTo-CSV) | Format-List
```

Remove the `| Format-List` if your resulting CSV isn't too wide to fit on the screen.